# Why is password reset being triggered without user submitting the form?

Tags: account-password

Multiple users are reporting their 'forgot password' / password reset function is being triggered, and that they're receiving emails with the verification code etc, even though they didn't request a password reset.

The forgot password / password reset form requires an email address input so I can't imagine how spam bots would be able to submit that form (without knowing users email address). So I am baffled.

How to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent this attack by implementing some low-grade authentication before firing the reset script.

You might use a recaptcha or automated math question, to stop automated (bot) attacks.

To more strenuously confront both bot and human attacks in a personalized fashion, have your users verify their account by answering a "secret question" (which was part of the registration process) before triggering the reset process.

Here's some additional reading:

- [Reset password - should I prevent abusing it?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/24280/208614)
- https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=957796 ([NeilRobertson](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/120/neil-robertson))
- https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/easycalccheck-plus/
- https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/simplecaptcha/
- https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/funcaptcha/
- https://www.kunena.org/forum/154-Miscellaneous-off-topic-and-general-Joomla/127752-how-to-add-security-question-when-registering